# How to re-create RAID1 really properly

Tags: linux-mint, partition, mdadm, software-raid, gpt

**System:**
Laptop with Linux Mint 17.3, 1x SSD for system and 2x HDD intended for RAID1 using `mdadm`.

**Situation:**
Without knowing how to create RAID1 properly, I created it badly.

- GParted showed a warning that a primary `gpt` partition table is not there, and that it is using the backup one, I think it showed this twice
- GParted showed the partition on both HDDs contained `ext4` filesystem, instead of `linux-raid` filesystem
- GParted did not show the `raid` flag on neither HDDs
- Reboot caused the array not to work, I mean not only it did not mount automatically, it could not be mounted without stopping the array and re-assembling it
- There were probably other things I did not notice like I don't know if the array, I mean the mirroring, even worked properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, let it be clear that all of your data will be destroyed on both of the array members (drives), so back it up first!

---

Open terminal and become [`root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) ([`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))); if you have [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) enabled, you may also do for example `sudo -i`; see [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for all options):

```
sudo -i
```

---

Check what number (`mdX`) the array has:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Suppose it is `md0` and it is mounted on `/mnt/raid1`, first we have to unmount and stop the array:

```
umount /mnt/raid1
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

We need to erase the super-block on both drives, suppose `sda` and `sdb`:

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1
```

---

Let's get to work; we should erase the drives, if there were any data and filesystems before, that is. Suppose we have 2 members: `sda`, `sdb`:

```
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sda
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
```

If you were to skip the previous step for your reasons, you need to wipe all filesystems on both of the drives. Then check if there is nothing left behind, you may peek with GParted on both of the drives, and if there is any filesystem other than `unknown`, wipe it.

First, we wipe all existing partitions, suppose `sda` contains 3 partitions, then:

```
wipefs --all /dev/sda3
wipefs --all /dev/sda2
wipefs --all /dev/sda1
```

Use this on both of the drives and do all partitions there are.

Then, we wipe the partition scheme with:

```
wipefs --all /dev/sda
wipefs --all /dev/sdb
```

---

Then, we initialize both drives with GUID partition table (GPT):

```
gdisk /dev/sda
gdisk /dev/sdb
```

In both cases use the following:

`o` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision
`w` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write changes
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision

Now, we need to partition both of the drives, but don't do this with GParted, because it would create a filesystem in the process, which we don't want, use `gdisk` again:

```
gdisk /dev/sda
gdisk /dev/sdb
```

In both cases use the following:
`n` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for first partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the first sector
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the last sector
`fd00` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for Linux RAID type
`w` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write changes
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision

---

To triple-check if there is nothing left behind, you may peek with GParted on both of the newly created partitions, and if they contain any filesystem other than `unknown`, wipe it:

```
wipefs --all /dev/sda1
wipefs --all /dev/sdb1
```

---

You can examine the drives now:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

It should say:

> ```
> (type ee)
> ```

If it does, we now examine the partitions:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

It should say:

> ```
> No md superblock detected
> ```

---

If it does, we can create the RAID1 array:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

We shall wait until the array is fully created, this process we may watch with:

```
watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat
```

After creation of the array, we should look at its detail:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

It should say:

> ```
>           State : clean
>  Active Devices : 2
> Working Devices : 2
>  Failed Devices : 0
>   Spare Devices : 0
> ```

---

Now we create filesystem on the array, if you use `ext4`, this is better to be avoided, because of `ext4lazyinit` would take noticeable amount of time, hence the name, "lazyinit", therefore I recommend you to avoid this one:

> mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0

Instead, you should force a full instant initialization with:

```
mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/md0
```

By specifying these options, the inodes and the journal will be initialized immediately during creation, useful for larger arrays.

If you chose to take a shortcut and created the `ext4` filesystem with the "better avoided command", note that `ext4lazyinit` will take noticeable amount of time to initialize all of the inodes, you may watch it until it is done, e.g. with:

```
iotop
```

Either way you choose to make the file system initialization, you should mount it after it has finished its initialization.

---

We now create some directory for this RAID1 array:

```
mkdir --parents /mnt/raid1
```

And simply mount it:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid1
```

Since we are essentially done, we may use GParted again to quickly check if it shows `linux-raid` filesystem, together with the `raid` flag on both of the drives.

If it does, we properly created the RAID1 array with GPT partitions and can now copy files on it.

---

See what UUID the `md0` filesystem has:

```
blkid /dev/md0
```

Copy the UUID to clipboard.

Now we need to edit `fstab`, with your favorite text editor:

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

And add add an entry to it:

```
UUID=<the UUID you have in the clipboard>    /mnt/raid1    ext4    defaults     0    0
```

You may check if it is correct, after you save the changes:

```
mount --all --verbose | grep raid1
```

It should say:

> ```
> already mounted
> ```

---

If it does, we save the array configuration; in case you don't have any `md` device yet created, you can simply do:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

In case there are arrays already existent, just run the previous command without redirection to the conf file:

```
mdadm --detail --scan
```

and add the new array to the `mdadm.conf` file manually.

---

In the end, don't forget to update your initramfs:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Check if you did everything according to plan, and if so, you may restart:

```
reboot --reboot
```